# DateTime format not showing correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

Firstly, apologies for asking a question that has been asked before, but even with the examples I am not getting the desired results.

All I am trying to do is display the current time, which it does, but I noticed that the datetime format was 9:5:6 instead of 09:05:06.  I read the examples about formatting DateTime but it doesn't work for some reason.  Can anyone shed any light on where I am going wrong?

Thanks for your help as always.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer dispatchTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatchTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatchTimer_Tick);
        dispatchTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatchTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dispatchTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var hour = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
        var min = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
        var sec = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
        var today = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
        label1.Content = today;
        textBlock1.Text = today;
        button1.Content = today;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Corak amazingly quick answer.

Comment: Slower than @Oded, so I deleted the comment and upvoted him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
var today = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Or the [standard one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx):

```
var today = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. If used in a culture like "Bengali (India)" where the "time separator" is `"."`, it will come out as e.g. "17.18.19".

Comment: `var today = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");` then?

Comment: Thank you, thank you and thrice thank you.  Easy when you know how aye!

Comment: That's interesting Jeppe, I thought the : was a global separator for time.

Comment: @Corak - thanks for that. Forgot there was a standard long-time format string.

Comment: @ullevi83 - Nope, in date/time format strings the `:` is replaced by the time separator for the specified locale (or the default locale if none is specified).

Answer (score 0):

```
string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Check [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396389.aspx) Class for more detailed globalization.

Comment: Why would you take a date, transform it into a string then split that string to take the date parts ? Just get the date and assign it to the required field.

Comment: Why not `var now = DateTime.Now; var hours = now.ToString("HH"); var minutes = now.ToString("mm"); var seconds = now.ToString("ss")`? But even then, why having seperate variables at all?

Comment: Honestly i thought he wanted it in parts, but then i saw that he combined them at the end, so my bad :)

Comment: @SirajMansour Even if he wanted it in part, it would be better (and faster) to just have a temporary `DateTime` variable and access the value directly than Formatting the date and splitting it back

Comment: you mean the way corak did it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to tackle this issue.

Personally, and to keep things simple, I would do it this way:

```
private void dispatchTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string wTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    // OR THIS WAY
    string wTime2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");

    label1.Content = wTime;
    textBlock1.Text = wTime;
    button1.Content = wTime;
}
```

But if you want for some reasons to keep your initial logic then this would do it too.

```
private void dispatchTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hour = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00");
    string min = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00");
    string sec = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("00");
    var today = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    label1.Content = today;
    textBlock1.Text = today;
    button1.Content = today;
}
```

You may also wish to look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx